# Printing PDFs in Google Chrome correctly

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, pdf, kibana

I'm working in Kibana and when I try to print pdfs in Google Chrome some of the info is cut off. It doesn't fit the whole width of the Dashboards.
If I add:

```
@media print {
  body{
    zoom:.4;
  }
}
```

It works, but it varies depending on resolution it seems. Is there any way to consistently fix this independent of resolution.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Or did you mean JavaScript? Read the description of the Java tag: *"Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript**, JScript or JS) ..."*

Comment: A typo, sorry & thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug and not something you should need to work around. Can you open an issue in the [Kibana repository](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues) and provide a way to reproduce your issue, please :)